# how to run appium test multiple times?

Tags: testng, appium, testng.xml

I am currently using appium + testng for testing native apps. I am running test from the **.xml** file. I want to run test multiple times i.e. after all the test run from testng.xml file, i want to run the same script again and again for few times.

Following is the sample of my testng.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Personalization Test" verbose="1">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="util.InvokedMethodListener"/>
</listeners>
<test name="Add Device" >
    <groups>
        <run>

            <include name="startAppiumServer"/>
            <include name="startApp_reset"/>
            <include name="welcome"/>
            <include name="tnc"/>
            <include name="permission"/>
            <include name="login"/>
            <include name="dashboard"/>

        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>           
        <class name="test_cases.StartServer"/>
        <class name="test_cases.WelcomeTest"/>
        <class name="test_cases.TermAndConditionTest"/>
        <class name="test_cases.PermissionTest"/>
    </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

After successfully executing above code i want to the same script multiple times, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an TestNG.xml file which contains multiple suites.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="Multiple Run Suite"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 
            <suite-files>
                   <suite-file path="./PersonalizationTest.xml" />
                   <suite-file path="./PersonalizationTest.xml" />
                   <suite-file path="./PersonalizationTest.xml" />
                   ...
            </suite-files>
    </suite>
```

Add suite-file path details for required suite as many times as you want to run the same test multiple times.